# Angular: Child Route Matching

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

Suppose we have the following routes:

```
{
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: BComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: CComponent,
            children: [
                { path: '', component: DComponent }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following URL is pasted into the browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost:4200/a
```

**Questions**

1. How does the Router know what component to display?
2. Would all the four components (A, B, C, D) be displayed?
3. Where would each component be displayed?

   - Does every parent component always have its own RouterOutlet, so each component along a route of parent/child/grand-child/etc. gets displayed inside its parent's respective RouterOutlet?
   - Usually, when displaying a route with child routes, each component is displayed inside its parent RouterOutlet. But, if only AComponent had a RouterOutlet, where would BComponent, CComponent and DComponent be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you aren't getting any sort of error the router will give you the first matching route it found. In this case BComponent. Only one component can be shown in a router outlet (to do otherwise you need something like auxRoute).

If CComponent had a route like 'c' you could access it from the route `http://localhost:4200/a/c` then you would get CComponent with DComponent in CComponents router outlet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. 1) So matching happens recursively from the lowest child and up? Since B and not A, is shown. 2) Would there not be multiple nested RouterOutlets? So B is shown at the bottom of A?

Comment: Do you think you could add some more information here? If the router searches from the top, it finds AComponent first, not BComponent.

Comment: In your example AComponent will always load. BComponent and CComponent will show is AComponents router-outlet. Again, you will need to add a value in the path for CComponent.
If you load `http://localhost:4200/a` AComponent will load with BComponent in its router outlet. 
When you add a path value to CComponent and navigate to `http://localhost:4200/a/c` You will get ACompnent with CComponent in AComponent's router-outlet and DComponent in CComponents router-outlet.

Comment: Thanks mgm, that's helpful. I also learned from a friend of mine that /a is actually /a/"". It is Only one empty level though. I.e /a is equal to /a/"", but not to /a/""/"". Is that right?